# cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to oauth2.googleapis.com:443

Tags: php

I am getting an error while pushing files from the server to google cloud storage

the error is like below

cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to oauth2.googleapis.com:443 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)heee

please help me to solve this

below is my code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

 $storage = new StorageClient([ 'keyFilePath' => 'facebooth_bucket.json']);
 $bucketName = 'fb-uploads';

$uploadDocument = isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) ? $_FILES['uploaded_file'] : '';

$uploaddir = "uploads/";

if (isset($uploadDocument['name']) && !empty($uploadDocument['name'])) {

                $uploadFileName = str_replace(" ","_",basename($uploadDocument['name']));

                $ext = pathinfo($uploadFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $fileName = str_replace("." . $ext, "", $uploadFileName);


                $uploadFileName = $fileName . "_" . date('his') . '.' . $ext;

                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $uploadFileName;
                // die($uploadfile);

                if (move_uploaded_file($uploadDocument['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

                    if(file_exists($uploadfile)) {
                        try {
                                $objectName = $uploadFileName;

                                $file = fopen($uploadfile, 'r');
                                $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
                                $object = $bucket->upload($uploadfile, [
                                    'name' => $objectName
                                ]);
                                printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($uploadFileName), $bucketName, $objectName);
                            // require_once __DIR__ . "/google_storage/vendor/autoload.php";
                            // $storage = new StorageClient([
                            //     'keyFilePath' => '/var/www/html/crewbies/upload_testing/google_storage/key/facebooth_bucket.json'
                            // ]);
                            // $bucket =  $storage->bucket('fb-uploads');
                            // $bucket->upload(
                            //     fopen('/china/$uploadfile', 'r')
                            // );
                        }
                        catch(Exception $e) {
                            $err = $e->getMessage();
                            print_r($err);
                            die('heee');
                        }

                    }

                }


            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Hello! Can you tell us how are you trying to do this? Maybe posting a snippet of your code would help :)

Comment: i added my code

Comment: @GuilhermeAssemany  do you  know to upload files to subfolder in bucket from above code?